# How to use XWiki a CMS for a web site?

Tags: xwiki

I want to build a web site with wiki and blog. It seems that XWiki could do all these. Could I create 3 spaces:

1. Default "static" web site
2. Wiki
3. Blog

If so, how do I configure the default site so to the public, it has no wiki features visible at all, and I have complete control over it's content and design?

Answer (score 1):

XWiki can be indeed configured at Space layer about Presentation (skin, color theme, layout...) and Rights. So it's possible to run those 3 kinds of site in the same XWiki instance, no need to separate them! :-)

It's all over customization, just create three spaces with the names you want, and change rights accordingly. You can find some cool skins (including one made for public website) on http://extensions.xwiki.org

It's not so complicated, I hope you'll find what you're searching for

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but the primary question is about how to deal with the "static" web site part. I found this http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Leiothrix+Skin but I don't see simple explanation of how to customize the look and feel and manage the content.

Comment: Leiothrix is the perfect skin for you public website. Once you've installed it, you can set it in the Administration panel of the space you want (look at the top bar when you're logged). Look and feel can be changed here. Either you change the style, or easier, you change the colortheme with the bundled editor.
And the horizontal menu will be configured in the special administration section (that you can find in the global admin, not the current space admin) dedicated to Leiothrix.